# Find the characteristic equation in terms of $p$ rather than $\lambda$ in second order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**

Consider the following second-order differential equation with constant coefficients,

$$y''\left(x\right)-10\,y'\left(x\right)+41\,y\left(x\right)=0$$

By seeking solutions of the form $z(x)=e^{px}$,determine the characteristic equation in terms of $p$ (rather than the usual $\lambda\,$). Enter the characteristic equation below, including the equals sign, ”=”.

---

I know that the characteristic equation for this is obviously :

$$\lambda^2-10\lambda+41=0$$

And usually we then go onto find the solutions.

But I dont understand how to find the characteristic equation in terms of $p$ (the solutions which is obviously equal to $0$).

**P.S**
*The solution for the characteristic equation is*
$\;\lambda=3\pm 4i$

Comment: Should that say $y''(x)-10y'(x)+41y(x)=0$?

Comment: @BenS. ops yes thanks :)

Comment: It just means, use $p$ as your variable instead of $\lambda$.

Comment: Also, think what role $\lambda$ plays in your solution. If you replace $\lambda$ by the letter $p$, what can you say?

Comment: what? just write p instead of lambda?

Comment: @M.S.E, how do you think, what is characteristic equation?

Comment: @M.S.E for the question in chat, you let $e^x=1/y$, complete the square in denominator, and then use the integral representation of $\operatorname{arcsinh}(a x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assume that the solution for your equation $\ y\,''\!\left(x\right)-10\,y\,'\!\left(x\right)+41\,y\left(x\right)=0\ $ 
looks like $\ y\left(x\right) = e^{\,px},\,  $ all you need to obtain characteristic polynomial is to substitute $\ y\left(x\right) = e^{\,px}\, $ into the equation.

First, compute derivatives of $y$:
$$
y \left(x\right) = e^{\,px} \implies y\,'\!\left(x\right) = pe^{\,px}, \implies y\,''\!\left(x\right) = p^2 e^{\,px}
$$

Second, substitute into equation:
$$
y\,''\!\left(x\right)-10\,y\,'\!\left(x\right)+41\,y\left(x\right)=0 \quad\mapsto\quad
p^2 e^{\,px} - 10\, p\,e^{\,px} + 41 e^{\,px} = 0
$$
Since $e^{\,px} \neq 0$, we divide both sides of equation by $e^{\,px}$, thus obtaining *characteristic polynomial*:
$$
\bbox[4pt, border: solid 1.5pt #100000]{p^2 - 10\, p + 41 =0}
$$